# Failing to alter page size with geometry package

Tags: geometry, posters

I want to create a poster 11'' x 17'' in size. This code

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[height=11in,width=17in,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

yields a page 8.5'' x 11''. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that you are using landscape. There is a portrait also.

Comment: Yes, but [ideally] I want the landscape orientation.

Comment: Use `\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=17in,margin=1cm]{geometry}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the paper dimensions use

```
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=17in,margin=1cm]{geometry}
```

Also, you can pass `landscape` or `portrait` options to `geometry` instead of to the class.

To change text dimensions use `textheight` and `textwidth` within `geometry`.